# Freeing up buffer space after use in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-datalab

So I'm using Google Cloud data Lab and I use the %%storage read command to read in a large file (2,000,000 rows) Into the `text` variable and then I have to process it into a pandas dataframe using BytesIO eg `df_new=pd.read_csv(BytesIO(text))`

So now I don't need the `text` Variable or its contents around, (all further processing is done on `df_new`, how can I delete it (`text`) and free up memory (I sure don't need two copies of a 2 million record dataset hanging around...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `del` followed by forced garbage collection.

```
import gc

# Remove text variable
del text
# Force gc collection - this not actually necessary, but may be useful.
gc.collect()
```

Note that you may not see process size decreasing and memory returning to OS, depending on memory allocator used (depends on OS, core libraries used and python compilation options).